# Is it correct to say "depending on that"?

Tags: expressions

I was taking notes and I've written:

> Our "State" class can either be "StartState" or "StopState" **and depending on that** we'll have different functionalities

Is that correct? Idk why but it doesn't sound so xD

Thanks for your time and please feel free to correct any other mistakes I've made!

Have a nice day!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: I have asked a similar question like you. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/148305/depend-usage-in-present-continuous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's obviously correct but you can say that.

- Our "State" class can either be "StartState" or "StopState" and depending on that we'll have different functionalities.

What actually happens here is that you omit some word that refers to *(which word it is is unknown, which isn't pleasing actually)*.