# "Depend" usage in present continuous

Tags: word-usage

Refer below image from the book "Essential Grammar in use" by Raymond Murphy,

[image]

The image shows that we do not use those verbs in the present continuous as "I am -ing", but I have seen some sentences like this **"I'm depending on you"**

Please clarify, Thanks in advance

Comment: Also google ngram shows more results for "depending on" than "depend on". https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Depend+on%2Cdepending+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDepend%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdepending%20on%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, the answer is a resounding yes, but in reality these rules can sometimes be "broken". And native speakers actually would not even be able to tell you whether they're breaking anything. ***I'm depending on you***, ***I'm loving it*** (that's a catch phrase from one of the McDonald's TV commercials, as far as I know) and ***I'm remembering now*** (though the meaning here is a tad different from ***I remember that***) are three such examples. There are probably many more. But, again, in general the book is right.

Answer (score 5):

I can't see anything wrong with "I am depending on you." However, a pedant might insist on "I depend on you," but this is rather old-fashioned. If the author had written "We do not *normally* use these verbs in the present continuous," and then given some exceptions, I would be happier. He is being too prescriptive.

Comment: I'd distinguish between "I depend on you" (in general or habitually) and "I'm depending on you" (for a specific present or future arrangement to be fulfilled).

Answer (score 0):

Mine is pretty simple.
Why use extra ‘ing’ when it sounds simpler and sweeter without it. And yes, means exactly what one wishes to express.

Breaking the rule for the sake of sounding unique in the world of advertisement is a completely different area of argument.